# How do I call this subroutine from a button click on an Access form?

Tags: vba, ms-access

So, dumb question, but I can't figure it out. I have the following code that searches for a file path name and I believe adds the record to a table (untested). But, the problem is I am unable to Call this subroutine. I'd like to be able to click a button on a form and run. Does anyone know how I do this? thank you!

```
Public Function SelectFile() As String

Dim f As FileDialog
Set f = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogOpen)

With f
    .AllowMultiSelect = False
    .Title = "Please select file to attach"
    If .Show = True Then
        SelectFile = .SelectedItems(1)
    Else
        Exit Function
    End If
End With

Set f = Nothing

End Function


Public Sub AddAttachment(ByRef rstCurrent As DAO.Recordset, ByVal strFieldName As String, ByVal strFilePath As String)

Dim dbs As DAO.Database
Dim rst As DAO.Recordset

'Ask the user for the file
Dim filepath As String
filepath = SelectFile()

'Check that the user selected something
If Len(filepath) = 0 Then
    Debug.Assert "No file selected!"
    Exit Sub
End If

Set dbs = CurrentDb
Set rst = dbs.OpenRecordset("Table1")

''''change this
'Add a new row and an attachment

rst.AddNew
AddAttachment rst, "Files", filepath
rst.Update

'Close the recordset
rst.Close
Set rst = Nothing
Set dbs = Nothing

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would add an event procedure to the button in question:

1. In Form Design mode, click on the button
2. In the Properties Sheet, select the builder [...] button of the On Click event
3. You will go to the VBA editor. Enter code like:

   `Private Sub cmdAddAttachment_Click()
       AddAttachment Nothing, "", ""
   End Sub`

That said, your `AddAttachment` routine has an apparent infinite loop. The line:

```
AddAttachment rst, "Files", filepath
```

Doesn't seem to actually fill any field values. In fact, variables `rstCurrent`, `strFieldName` and `strFilePath` are not used in the code. You probably will need to debug this routine before it will work.